# directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i need help how to solved this error in XCode like this :

[image]

i'm stuck with these error all day, already check and build and keep got error..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: try to re-link the framework, then set allow bitcode to NO

Comment: thanks for reply..
but then how to re link the framework sir ? sorry i'm new with xcode...

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions for this ..

Just need to add this into your pods and pod install again :

pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'